# What does it mean if a patent's status is expired and grant?

Tags: expired, grant

I am looking to add a product to my online business but want to make sure I am not infringing any patents. Dog shoes have so many styles it is very confusing. Please see below:

Date App/Pub Number Status
2002-06-17 US10173363 Expired - Fee Related
2003-03-04 US6526920B1 Grant

2002 it is expired and then 2003 it says grant. What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

The first date (2002-06-17) is the filing date, US10173363 is the application number. The second date (2003-03-04) is the date of issuance of the patent, and US6529620B1 is the patent number.

And, yes, the patent has expired for not paying renewal fees, since 2015.

The words "expired-fee related" in that order simply means that the patent although granted, expired fue to fee-related reasons.